# How to save .jpg NOT .JPG

Tags: iphone, jpeg

When uploading photos from my iPhone to use for eBay they are automatically saved as .JPG (all caps). However eBay only recognizes .jpg. So I have to manually go back in and rename all the files with the lowercase .jpg.

Is there anyway to have them automatically be uploaded in .jpg and not .JPG, its very time consuming. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry you are in wrong place, go and ask this question in apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: `mount` has quite a few options to force upper/lowercase in filenames, no idea which apply here, but that question seems perfectly legit.

Comment: To those close-voters: Have we established that this person is not using Ubuntu? If they are copying from the iPhone to Ubuntu, then on to eBay this is on-topic.

Answer (score 10):

You make no mention of Ubuntu, but you posted this in AskUbuntu. I'm going to assume you are moving photos like this `iPhone -> Ubuntu -> eBay`, since anything else would probably be off-topic.

Shotwell can do this easily, it's in the preferences menu 'Rename imported files to lowercase':

[image: Shotwell prefs]

If Shotwell can't import directly from the iPhone, just copy the images to your Desktop and then import them into Shotwell from there.

Another easy option is to use `pyrenamer` from the software center. It's especially useful if you are doing lots of these retroactively, and you can also rename JPEGs based on embedded metadata like dates & times.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about changing how they are uploaded, but if you are uploading them to a folder on ubuntu, you can perform a mass rename to rename everything at once if it makes it easier.

Open up a terminal and type

```
cd /path/to/photos
rename 's/\.JPG$/.jpg/' *.JPG
```

And that will find all files in the directory ending with .JGP and change them to .jpg.

Comment: @Rinzwind `rename` is smart enough these days to know that a target file might exist. `$ touch x.jpg x.JPG; rename 's/\.JPG/.jpg/' x.JPG` gives `x.JPG not renamed: x.jpg already exists` with the rename from Perl 5.10.1. However, some older version apparently didn't handle that situation gracefully.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ok :) I said nothing then ;)

Comment: Oh @eltommo `rename.ul JPG jpg *.JPG` is easier to read >:)